# Bash find files with certain extension, but exclude those with certain keyword in filename

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I'm looking to run a search which looks for all files in a certain folder which have the extension of ".exr" and ".dpx". However, from that list I want to exclude files that contain 'BTY' in the name.

I'm not sure how to run this so that it removes the 'BTY' files from the list after searching, here is what I was trying.

```
find /Users/Tim/Downloads -type f -name "*.dpx" -o -name "*.exr" -o ! -type f -name "*BTY*.exr"
```

Thanks.

Comment: So if you want to find files with certain extension __and__ exclude those with keyword, it's __and__ `-a` not or `-o` operation. `!` is applied on `-type f` - you are excluding files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
find /Users/Tim/Downloads -type f -name "*.dpx" -o '(' -name "*.exr" -a '!' -name "*BTY*.exr" ')'
```

Find files named `*.dpx` or ( named `*.exr` and not named `*BTY*.exr` ).

Comment: Thanks! This worked, the parentheses makes sense, I will remember that.